# Specifying assembly version of all projects within a web deployment wdproj script

Tags: msbuild

I have a .wdproj Web Deployment Project created with VS2010 that contains references to other class libraries, like this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Path\Proj1.csproj">
      <Project>{GUID-HERE}</Project>
      <Name>Proj1</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Path\Proj2.csproj">
      <Project>{GUID-HERE}</Project>
      <Name>Proj2</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
```

There are lots of these. I want to be able to run `msbuild /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release` and have all the assemblies of all the included projects compiled at a specified version. Nothing fancy just static like 2.5.6.0 and specified once in the wdproj file. I dont want to open 30 files manually.

I have looked at MSBuild Community Task and MSBuildExtension Pack and can not get anything to work. The build runs ok without errors.

Anyone have an example of how this can be done?

This is an attempt with MSBuild Extensions (adapted from the sample included) that doesn't work:

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.VersionNumber.targets"/>

  <Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.AssemblyInfo
      ComVisible="true"
      AssemblyInfoFiles="VersionInfo.cs"
      AssemblyFileMajorVersion="2" 
      AssemblyFileMinorVersion="5"
      AssemblyFileBuildNumber="6"
      AssemblyFileRevision="0"
    />

  </Target>
```

MSBuild is definately looking at the `MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.AssemblyInfo` element because if the attribute names are incorrect the build will fail. This builds ok but none of the versions on the referenced assemblies are changed. The version numbers on the ASP.NET page assemblies from the website are all 0.0.0.0.

Comment: As an alternative there is http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2010/12/07/simple-msbuild-configuration-updating-assemblies-with-a-version-number.aspx but requires some re-arrangment of the AssemblyInfo.cs details of each project first.

Answer (score 0):

Are you maybe missing to specify the CodeLanguage and OutputFile attributes?
I think the AssemblyInfo task is intended to generate (replace) a source file prior to compiling.

Comment: Do you mean on the AssemblyInfo class? The docs http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.2.0/index.html don't seem to mention these two.

Comment: Sorry: I am looking at the MSBuild Community Tasks (http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/).

Comment: No problem, so much time spent on this... wondering if there is an alternative build tool that is easier to use.